# Background-image for a flex-container

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am trying to set a background image for a flex-container. However, it doesn't seem to appear.
Does anyone know why? Thanks.

css:

```
.sidebar { 
            display: flex;
            height: 710px;
            width: 30%;
            flex-flow: column wrap;
            align-content: center; 
            font-family: 'OpenSans, OpenSans-Regular';
            background-image: url("/images/IMAGE2.png");
            background-position: center; 
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover; 
}
```

I don't see any error, as I've compared it to online examples. There is a background colour to the body, but it doesn't seem to affect other images.

Comment: maybe you want *relative* path instead of absolute. `url('./images/IMAGE2.png')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a folder to store your CSS files and another to store images. If that's the case, you will have to go to the parent directory and open the images folder using **`..`** before the forward slash `/`.

```
background-image: url("../images/IMAGE2.png");
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't mention the image address correctly. I just try it with one example to make sure and it is working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: green;
  background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/736x/3b/af/e6/3bafe638ffbd522cb450f81235d87426.jpg");
  background-position: center; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px 100px; 
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>The flex-direction Property</h1>

<p>The "flex-direction: column;" stacks the flex items vertically (from top to bottom):</p>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]